# Call function from argument of another function

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I need to call a function in different function from its arguments.

```
class LST {
public:
  char *value;
  LST *Next;
};
bool Is_Even(LST *el) {
  return true;
}    
void For_Each_el(LST *&el, bool f) {
  LST *H = el;
  while (H) {
    if (f(H)) //this line causes the error
      Current = H;
    H = H->Next;
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
error C2064: the result of evaluating the fragment is not a function that takes one argument
```

(translated from russian)

So, this code doesn't work.

Here is how I call it in the `main()` function:

```
int main() {
  Head = new LST;
  Head->value = "4";
  For_Each_el(Head, Is_Even(Head));
  _getch();
}
```

Comment: `bool f` is a Boolean parameter named `f`. You are calling it like it was a function pointer. Also of note: you don't have/show a constructor, so you can't expect `Next` to be initialized to `nullptr`, and if you want `value` to be a string, use `std::string`.

Comment: @GALIAF95 Your C++ code looks a lot like C code. Perhaps a book or a tutorial would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a typedef to a function pointer:

```
typedef bool(*test_LST)(LST*);
```

Then change the signature of your for each function:

```
void For_Each_el(LST *&el, test_LST f)
```

finally change how you call it in main:

```
For_Each_el(Head, Is_Even);
```

You can also use a `typedef std::function<bool(LST*)> test_LST;` instead of the above typedef to allow for function object for-each iteration, or write `For_Each_el` as a `template` function.